# Programmatically copy emails from one Microsoft 365 user to another

Tags: office365, exchange-server

We're looking for a good way to programmatically copy emails from one Microsoft 365 user to another (dynamically, based on email sender and recipient).

It should be a complete clone of the message, not a forwarded copy.

Graph API doesn't seem to have a method for that.

We tried Exchange mail flow rules, but it became too complicated, prone to duplicate messages, and hitting the limit on the number of recipients.

We also tried the Search-Mailbox PowerShell cmdlet, but it creates a subfolder for each invocation instead of putting messages into Inbox. And it's deprecated.

The best we could make so far is to setup a notification subscription for new emails via Graph API and manually compose a copy of the message, sending it via an external SMTP. The problem is that it's not a perfect clone of the message as we can't fake the "from" property.

Could anyone please suggest any other viable alternatives?

Company email workflow is extra-rigid, they don't want to setup groups or shared email accounts or anything else but plain personal email accounts.

**Update**: for now we ended up developing an app what allows to define teams and automatically creates mail flow (transport) rules for both incoming (1 rule per team to avoid the recipients limit and duplication) and outgoing (1 rule per team member to avoid duplication) emails.